# How To Update Cordova on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Hello I have Cordova installed with Visual Studio 2017, the only version I can see in the "Visual Studio Installer" is Cordova 4.3.1.

The issue is I don't know how to install the new version of Cordova. I know when I do get it installed I will find it in the projects config. I need to updated so that I can use OneSignal plugin for notifications I have tried following along side the online help guides provided by Microsoft but none of them say how to install the new version only change the one used.

How can I update my Cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest supported version from the menu in Visual Studio 2017

Tools | Get Tools and Features

Scroll down to mobile development and select it. However this will only give you the latest Microsoft Supported version (currently 6 while cordova is up to version 8, and many plugins require 7 or higher.).

If there is a later version that you want to use then you need to install cordova on your development PC standalone (see https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html).

Then in visual studio (you'll have to restart it for the new install to be recognised) open your projects config.xml, and on the toolset tab you can select your external version of cordova.

**EDIT** The form view of the config.xml is flakey... the drop down may not show your external installation, so edit the xml as text (right click, view code) and update these lines to the versions you want to target.

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>8.1.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
<engine name="ios" spec="4.2.0" />
<engine name="windows" spec="^4.4.2" />
```